# Is it permissible to do Salat in a non-Muslim's house?

Tags: salat, adhan

I currently work as a private tutor for a middle-school girl. She and her family are non-Muslims.
My tutoring job starts at 4.30 PM and ends at 6.30 PM. I come to their house to tutor the girl. Adhan for Maghrib prayer (salat) comes in the middle of teaching time, at about 5.49 PM.

Shall I wait till 6.30 PM to do Salat in the nearby Masjid (mosque) or shall I just do Salat in the middle of teaching, and in their house? With knowing that Maghrib time ends at about 7.00 PM?

I just feel kind of awkward to do Salat in their house. But either, I don't wanna hurt their feelings to leave the house at the beginning of maghrib time to do salat and come back again to tutor their daughter.

Is there anything in Islam that rules where we do Salat and where we don't?

Thanks.

Comment: You can pray salah after your work too, if there is time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Islam is the simplest of all religions and it poses no inconvenience
>   in leading life according to its principle or practicing its rituals. 
>   Athough a Masjid (Mosque) is the formal place for offering Salah
>   (Prayers), a Muslim can offer Salah (Prayers) anywhere.  There is a
>   Hadith (Saying of Muhammad S) that the entire earth is made for
>   Muslims a Masjid (Mosque) Salah (Prayers) can be offered at any place
>   that is clean.  One cannot offer Salah (Prayers) on dirty, filthy, or
>   impure place like a garbage dump, a cattleshed etc."

So be peaceful about doing your salat at their place, as long as it is clean.

You can find more in [here](http://www.islam4theworld.net/islam/pillars/salah/place_of__salah.htm)

Comment: Yeah, thank you for your answer, Brother. Hope ALLAH help me to perform Salah well in their house. Aamiin..

Comment: @Safira, accept the answer if it is useful. :)

Answer (score 3):

I think you can perform your prayer anywhere in the world as long as the place is clean and there is no visible picture or sculpture in the place. Just to clarify, Omar Ibn Farooq's family converted to Islam before he did and I am pretty sure they all performed their Islamic rituals even though the place technically belonged to Omar.

Comment: "The place" you mean here, is it the entire house or the room (in the house) I do salat? (So if there is sculpture in the living room and I do salat in a maid room for example, is okay?) Thank you.

Comment: The room. You cannot control the whole building. Allah knows best.