# Is private-tutoring a bit younger opposite-sex is considered a Khalwa?

Tags: quran, hadith

Salaam.

This is a follow-up to a previous question of mine, [here](https://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/9893/is-it-permissible-to-do-salat-in-a-non-muslims-house).

My ex-junior at my college (I've just graduated last month) asks me to be ***his*** private tutor in preparing for a final exam in order for him to get a bachelor degree as I've achieved a while ago. The exams is a ***very* difficult** comprehensive test that tests students on all subjects the school's been teaching from the very 1st semester at college

He admitted that he once nearly failed his study because his GPA was not good enough. Then he said he's afraid that he won't be able graduate if he fails this final exam.

I'd like to help him graduate. But I couldn't bring myself to tutor him if it were just the two of us studying (me teaching him), even though the teaching job is being done in public places.

Meanwhile, as I ever heard of it, ikhtilat (intermingling of the sexes) is permissible in these circumstances: *in a medical treatment, at a market, and in the class (a teacher teaching his/her class)*.

So, is it permissible in Islam, if I accepted his offer to teach him, and there will be only *just* the two of us discussing the subjects?  Is it considered as khalwa as well?

I'd rather reject his wish anyway, it's so ***not*** comfortable to be with opposite-sex. Even though I'm the teacher and he's the student.

But still, I feel bad for him getting so much scared of failing the exam.

So, I'm looking for an answer that is based on Quran and Hadith for this matter. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Wsalam wr wb
I hope that this might answer your question up to a level.

http://islamqa.info/en/146441

http://islamqa.info/en/106509

The above two links quote the following:

> It is not permissible for a man to be alone with a woman who is not
>   his mahram, because the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon
>   him) said: “No man should be alone with a woman unless there is a
>   mahram with them.” Narrated by al-Bukhaari (1862) and Muslim (1341).
>   And he (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) said: “No man is
>   alone with a woman but the Shaytaan is the third one present.”
>   Narrated by al-Tirmidhi (1171) and classed as saheeh by al-Albaani in
>   Saheeh al-Tirmidhi.
>
> Al-Nawawi (may Allah have mercy on him) narrated in Sharh Muslim
>   (14/153) that there was consensus among the scholars that it is haraam
>   for a man to be alone with a woman who is not his mahram. This was
>   narrated by al-Haafiz in al-Fath (4/77).

And:

> The one who finds that he needs to bring a teacher for his daughter must make sure that >someone sits with them during the lesson, such as her brother, or he should make sure that >the lesson is given in an open area of the house, such as the sitting room, for example, and >not in a closed room.

wallahu alam

Comment: Salam and Welcome to Islam.SE, please consider editing your answer with the content from the link that you have provided. It will be better. :)

Comment: -1. OP's question were never directly addressed. And a public place usually means an open area. Plus [Do we want cut-and-paste answers?](http://meta.islam.stackexchange.com/q/324/3487)